Migration Data - New table already has data & both tables have a self-referencing FK
Environment
SQL Server 2019. I have 2 tables with very different schemas, including their PK column's data type. Both tables have a pseudo self-referencing foreign key. By pseudo, I mean that if you added the self-referencing foreign key to the table it wouldn't complain, but there isn't actually a FK constraint on the table.
Goal
The goal is to migrate all of the data from one table to the other.
Constraints

The target table already has existing data that can't be touched.
The target table's PK is an identity column.
The pseudo self-referencing foreign key must still be valid after the migration is done.
The target table's schema can't be changed.

What I've done
I can easily populate all the data in the target table using
INSERT INTO [target table] (...) 
    SELECT ... 
    FROM [source table]

The problem is that new PK values will be auto-generated in this process, which then have to backfill to a different row during the insert.
I really don't want to do this RBAR style, but I know I could do it that way within my migration script.
Question
Is there some way to handle this using set-based logic?
Thanks in advance.

Use a merge statement for your insert and use the output clause to return you the old id and the new id, use this table as a lookup (join) to update your FKs to point to the correct new ID. Dup here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172454/how-to-copy-migrate-data-to-new-tables-with-identity-column-while-preserving-fk

Thanks.  I'd never heard of the MERGE statement before.  Sometimes knowing what to search for to find the answer is the hard part because you don't know what you don't know.

I just searched for you question title and found that link in the top 5 :) so seems you knew more than you thought.

I found a similar question, but the accepted answer was a RBAR style solution.  I didn't go through all the Google results, but the page that you linked to isn't near the top.
